# Strip Poker game

Tags: python, game

I've made a short simple strip poker game. It follows the traditional rules of poker (4 of a kind>flush>straight,etc.), one round of betting followed by an option to change cards, then another round of betting (if cards were exchanged). It is played in the terminal, and uses Tkinter to display/change the photos depending on how much money the player has won. There are 10 folders, each with 5 sets of images (so you can play multiple hands and see multiple models). I'm not very familiar with OOP, or proper use of functions/classes (which is why there are globals strewn around everywhere, and the only class there I took from an example).

As a result, I'm primarily looking for just feedback/suggestions on how to improve the code. I wrote this for fun just to learn python and get better at programming (especially how to write cleaner/more organized code).
So any/all feedback is greatly appreciated. And yes, this one works consistently now 100% of the time.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
import random
import itertools
import threading

path=['Images1','Images2','Images3','Images4','Images5','Images6','Images7','Images8','Images9','Images10']

Images=('mountain.jpg')
class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, *pargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *pargs)

        self.image = Image.open(Images)
        self.img_copy= self.image.copy()

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

        self.background = Label(self, image=self.background_image)
        self.background.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        self.background.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

    def _resize_image(self,event):
        new_width = event.width
        new_height = event.height

        self.image = self.img_copy.resize((new_width, new_height))

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.background.configure(image =  self.background_image)

    def change_image(self, file):
        """Change background image of the window."""
        size = (self.winfo_width(), self.winfo_height())
        self.image = Image.open(file).resize(size)
        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.background.configure(image=self.background_image)

cards=['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K']

card_types=['♠', '♦', '♥', '♣']
#Creates a deck of 52 cards so you don't get any duplicates
combined_deck=itertools.product(cards,card_types)
deck=[]
for sublist in list(map(list,combined_deck)):
    deck.append(''.join(sublist))

card_faces={'J':'11','Q':'12','K':'13','A':'14','♠':'16','♦':'17','♥':'18','♣':'19'}

win_names={1:'Straight Flush',2:'4 of a kind',3:'full house',4:'Flush',5:'straight',6:'3 of a kind',7:'2 pair',8:'1 pair'}

high_card_names={1:'1',2:'2',3:'3',4:'4',5:'5',6:'6',7:'7',8:'8',9:'9',10:'10',11:'Jack',12:'Queen',13:'King',14:'Ace'}


players_winnings=[100,100,100,100]
players=[[],[],[],[]]
players_hand=[[],[],[],[]]
number_of_players=int(input('how many players are at the table?'))
pot=0
def hand_setup():
    """ setups the hand, everyone gets a random assortment of 5 cards from the deck"""
    global players
    global players_hand
    for i in range(number_of_players):
        players[i]+=(random.sample(deck,5))
        for values in players[i]:
            players_hand[i].append(values[0:-1])
            players_hand[i].append(values[-1])

def betting():
    """First round of betting, here you may also exchange your cards if you wish and go through a 2nd round of betting"""
    global pot
    global players_winnings
    pot_round_1=input(f'How much money would you like to bet\n Current Amount: {players_winnings[0]} ')
    for i in range(number_of_players):
        players_winnings[i]-=int(pot_round_1)
    pot+=(int(pot_round_1))*number_of_players
    trade_hands=input('if there are any cards you would like to exchange, type the index of the cards e.g. 01234 (otherwise, click enter): ')
    if trade_hands != '':
        for i in trade_hands:
            while True:
                players_hand[0][(int(i)*2)]=random.choice(cards)
                players_hand[0][(int(i)*2+1)]=random.choice(card_types)
                if (''.join(players_hand[0][(int(i)*2):(int(i)*2+2)])) not in players:
                    break
        print(f'Your New Hand\n{["".join(x) for x in zip(*[iter(players_hand[0])]*2)]}')
        print(f'Current Pot {pot}')
        pot_round_2=input(f'How much money would you like to bet\n Current Amount: {players_winnings[0]} ')
        pot+=(int(pot_round_2))*number_of_players
        for i in range(number_of_players):
            players_winnings[i]-=int(pot_round_2)


check_list=[[],[],[],[]]
def convert_hand():
    """To simplify the analysis of your hand, all face cards are converted to numbers using the above dict"""
    global check_list
    converted_list=[[],[],[],[]]
    adding_one_1=0
    for i in range(number_of_players):
        for x in players_hand[i]:
            if x == ' ':
                continue
            try:
                if x == 'A':
                    adding_one_1+=1
                    if adding_one_1<2:
                        converted_list[i].append(1)
                converted_list[i].append(int(card_faces[x]))
            except:
                converted_list[i].append(int(x))
        check_list[i].append(sorted(converted_list[i]))

doubles=[]
triples=[]
quads=[]
straight=[]
winning_hands=[]
highest_card=[]
card_type=[]
def analyze_hand():
    """The hand is then analyzed, and you look for doubles, triples, quads, etc. These are given a numberical value to determine who has the best hand"""
    global doubles
    global triples
    global quads
    global straight
    global winning_hands
    global highest_card
    global card_type
    current=[]
    for i in range(number_of_players):
        counter=0
        first_value=0
        current.clear()
        straight.clear()
        quads.clear()
        doubles.clear()
        triples.clear()
        flattened_check_list=[item for sublist in check_list[i] for item in sublist]
        if flattened_check_list[0]==1:
            highest_card.append(max(flattened_check_list[0:6]))
        else:
            highest_card.append(max(flattened_check_list[0:5]))
        for numbers in flattened_check_list:
            first_value+=1
            if first_value<2:
                current.append(numbers)
                straight.append(numbers)
                continue
            else:
                if numbers>15:
                    card_type.append(numbers)
                    continue
                if numbers == (current[0]+1):
                    straight.append(numbers)
                if numbers == current[0]:
                    counter+=1
                    if counter == 1:
                        doubles+=(current+[numbers])
                        current.clear()
                        current.append(numbers)
                        continue
                    if counter == 2:
                        triples+=(doubles[0:2]+[numbers])
                        current.clear()
                        doubles.clear()
                        current.append(numbers)
                        continue
                    if counter == 3:
                        quads+=(triples[0:3]+[numbers])
                        current.clear()
                        current.append(numbers)
                        continue
                else:
                    counter=0
                    current.clear()
                    current.append(numbers)
        print(f'player{i+1} has\n{["".join(x) for x in zip(*[iter(players_hand[i])]*2)]}')
        if len(straight) == 5 and card_type[0] == ((sum(card_type)/len(card_type))):
            print(((sum(card_type)/len(card_type))))
            winning_hands.append(1)
        elif len(quads) == 4:
            winning_hands.append(2)
        elif (len(doubles)+len(triples)) == 5:
            winning_hands.append(3)
        elif card_type[0] == ((sum(card_type)/len(card_type))):
            winning_hands.append(4)
        elif len(straight) == 5:
            winning_hands.append(5)
        elif len(triples) == 3:
            winning_hands.append(6)
        elif len(doubles) == 4:
            winning_hands.append(7)
        elif len(doubles) == 2:
            winning_hands.append(8)
        else:
            winning_hands.append(9)

def determine_winner():
    """The lower the number, the higher the hand. If no one has a set, then the highest card wins. If a tie, then everyone in the tie wins, and the pot is split"""
    global pot
    global highest_card
    global winning_hands
    global player_number
    #print(f'\n\n{straight}\n\n')
    winner=min(winning_hands)
    winner_list=[]
    indexer=0
    if winner == 9:
        highest_card_win=max(highest_card)
        highest_card_win_player=highest_card.index(highest_card_win)
        print(f'\nplayer {highest_card_win_player+1} won with {high_card_names[highest_card_win]} high')
        players_winnings[highest_card_win_player]+=pot
    else:
        for i in winning_hands:
            if i == winner:
                winner_list.append(indexer)
            indexer+=1
        if len(winner_list)>1:
            print('\nTie')
            new_pot=0
            new_pot+=(pot/len(winner_list))
            pot=new_pot
            for player_number in winner_list:
                print(f'\nplayer{player_number+1} won with {win_names[winner]}')
                players_winnings[player_number]+=pot
        else:
            winning_player=winning_hands.index(winner)
            print(f'\nplayer{(winning_player)+1} won with {win_names[winner]}')
            players_winnings[winning_player]+=pot

def reset():
    """All variables are reset to start the next round"""
    global doubles
    global triples
    global quads
    global straight
    global winning_hands
    global highest_card
    global pot
    global check_list
    global players
    global players_hand
    global card_type
    pot=0
    card_type.clear()
    doubles.clear()
    triples.clear()
    quads.clear()
    straight.clear()
    winning_hands.clear()
    highest_card.clear()
    check_list=[[],[],[],[]]
    players=[[],[],[],[]]
    players_hand=[[],[],[],[]]

def main(e,image_folder):
    global Images
    global players_winnings
    count=0
    """Main loop, you go until you or the other players run out of money"""
    while players_winnings[0]>1 and players_winnings[0]<(number_of_players*100):
        if players_winnings[0]<=100 and count==0:
            e.destroy()
            count+=1
            root.update()
            Images=image_folder+'/'+'image1.jpg'
            e = Example(root)
            e.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
            root.update()
        hand_setup()
        print(f'Your hand\n{players[0]}')
        betting()
        print(f'Current Pot {pot}')
        convert_hand()
        analyze_hand()
        determine_winner()
        reset()
        if players_winnings[0]>100 and count==1:
            count+=1
            e.destroy()
            Images=image_folder+'/'+'image2.jpg'
            e = Example(root)
            e.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
            root.update()
        if players_winnings[0]>((number_of_players*50)+25) and count==2:
            count+=1
            e.destroy()
            Images=image_folder+'/'+'image3.jpg'
            e = Example(root)
            e.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
            root.update()
        if players_winnings[0]>(number_of_players*75) and count==3:
            count+=1
            e.destroy()
            Images=image_folder+'/'+'image4.jpg'
            e = Example(root)
            e.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
            root.update()
        print('\nNext round\n')
    if players_winnings[0]<1:
        print('You have run out of money, you lose')
    else:
        print('Other players have run out of money, you win!')
        e.destroy()
        Images=image_folder+'/'+'image5.jpg'
        e = Example(root)
        e.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        root.update()
    return e

def game_loop():
    global players_winnings
    e = Example(root)
    e.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
    while True:
        image_folder=random.choice(path)
        players_winnings=[100,100,100,100]
        e = main(e,image_folder)
        if mb.askquestion('Replay', 'Would you like to play another round?') != 'yes':
            root.quit()
            break

root = tk.Tk()
screen_resolution=input('please indicate desired picture resolution (e.g. 1200x800)')
root.geometry(screen_resolution)
threading.Thread(target=game_loop).start()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I assume this displays images of all of the well-known strippers:  hot-air jet, sodium hydroxide, nitromethane and turpentine.

Comment: @Reinderien yep, and the infamous dihydrogen monoxide